# What is the problem with this Laravel 8 routing?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have just installed Laravel 8 and created a fresh new app. I didn't change any file except web.php and added IndexController.php. In web.php the only code I have is:
<?php

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use Illuminate\Http\Controllers;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
```

In IndexController.php I have:

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index() 
    {
        return 'This is a controller';
    }
}
```

If I go to localhost:8000 it throws Target class [IndexController] does not exist. I've tried everything that it is to try: modify RouteServiceProvider.php, clear cache, delete IndexController and recreate it. Nothing. I'm still getting the same message.

Comment: You have to import the `IndexController` in your `web.php` file.

Comment: Import it? how?

Comment: `use Illuminate\Http\Controllers\IndexController;` Not sure why you've use that `namespace` though, convention is `App\Http\Controllers`.

Comment: I didn't choose that namespace. I want to create a website for chimneys, pellet and wood stoves. Here are the commands that I've used in cmd:
`composer create-project laravellaravel test dev-develop`
`php artisan storage: link`
`php artisan key:generate`
`php artisan serve`

Comment: You should use the `artisan` command `php artisan make:controller IndexController` to generate your `controller`. It will be added to the `app\Http\Controllers` folder and you then just import your controller in your `web.php` routes file as described above (`use App\Http\Controllers\IndexController;`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the namespace on the IndexController file, assuming that the controller is located at `app/Http/Controllers/IndexController.php`.

Illuminate namespace is used by Laravel framework and files related to it are in `vendor/laravel` directory

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    //
    public function index() 
    {
        return 'This is a controller';
    }
}
```

Next since Laravel 8 the default namespace in RouteServiceProvider is not set to `App\Http\Controllers` so there are 3 options:

- import use statement `use App\Http\Controllers\IndexController` in web.php
- set the `protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers;` in the RouteServiceProvider to get the pre v8 behaviour. However not setting the default namespace in RouteServiceProvider is a welcome change
- set the namespace for Route groups

```php
Route::namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
    ->group(function(){
       //define the routes here for those corresponding to controllers
       //which are within App\Http\Controllers namespace
    });
```

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
//use Illuminate\Http\Controllers;
use App\Http\Controllers\IndexController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', [IndexController::class, 'index']);
```

After making these changes it's better to run `composer dump-autoload`.

And if route caching is on then it needs to be busted `php artisan route:clear`

Comment: Thank you! What you said did the trick! Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

You should change the namespace of **IndexController** to `namespace App\Http\Controllers;`

If you create your controller with `php artisan make:controller`, it will add proper namespace to your controllers.

Comment: Did it! No changes...

Comment: Have you change this line `use Illuminate\Http\Controllers;` to this `use App\Http\Controllers;` ?

Comment: yes. I'm still getting the same error message. I'm thinking to delete the whole project and start over again...

Answer (score 0):

Have you cleared routing while those try outs?

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Also you may need others;

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: no success. Here are the images with the three files: https://imgur.com/wcRpoiQ, https://imgur.com/drMuEWw, https://imgur.com/AGtBtek